# unable to update auto-refresh reference 'ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll and commonlogging.dll

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

> unable to update auto-refresh reference 'ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll and
> commonlogging.dll

I am getting this warning every time I build the project but the project is running fine without breaks in local system but I am getting error page in godaddy after uploading to server. is this the reason for 500 error in godaddy shared hosting server?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had this same problem with the AjaxControlToolkit. I've got no idea what caused it, but by simply re-installing the toolkit into my project with NuGet, that fixed it.

Install the package by following the steps below:

1. Right-click on your project and select Manage NuGet Packages.
2. Search the online repository for the package you want. In my case, this was 'ajaxcontroltoolkit'.
3. Find the package in the list of results that appears and click the Install button on it.

What this does is it removes all previous references of the package (older DLLs and references in your web.config file) and replaces them with newer, correct references

It's that simple.

Hope this helps you

Comment: I had the same issue after uninstalling nuget packages.  The solution for me was the remove the dependentAssembly references from web.config

Comment: This one does not work for me, I updated all packages but the warning still there. update the refresh file solve the problem.

Answer (score 12):

Look in the bin folder of the project - for a file called - in your case:

```
ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll.refresh
```

This will have an incorrect path to the dll file. You need to update the path to wherever the dll is now.

Comment: Same issue, solved by this answer, slightly different approach: Navigated to my bin/ folder, viewed the .refresh file, and it pointed to a location from another team  member's machine - who had installed and introduced the 3rd-party library to the project.  Since they placed the .dll right in the bin/ folder, all I had to do was delete the .refresh file - and all was well.

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue and manually creating a .refresh file for its DLL helped. Once I figured the origin of the relative path is the solution folder, and put that in the .refresh, everything worked for this and other references.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps somebody...
Im using VS2017 and had an ASP project with 28 Warnings:

> Unable to update auto-refresh reference 'XXXXX.dll'. Cannot find
>   assembly 'F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\Packages\…

...well...that **directory had been removed!**

To make matters worse (or better) when I create a new ASP project the references are handled a little different in solution explorer...and the assemblies referenced in the new project are in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared

To fix my warnings...I edited the .refresh file.

> You can do this by: 1: Double clicking the warning. 2: Navigate to it
>   in solution explorer under the Bin folder.

And changed (example)

```
..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\Packages\AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap.3.0.0\lib\net45\AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap.dll
```

to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Packages\AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap.3.0.0\lib\net45\AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue / what solved it for me was simply to do a "Refresh folder" on the Bin folder.